# Error: Invariant Violation: gatsby-source-graphql requires option `typeName` to be specified

Tags: graphql, gatsby

I am new to GatsbyJs - GraphQL, I have been exploring the example provided by gatsby(https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/tree/master/examples/using-gatsby-source-graphql), As I tried with local apollo-grapql server, It returns data in the front-end, However it throws above error and blocks the build process, not sure what exactly is typeName I need to pass it in here? any help one this would be much appreciated.

```
    `gatsby-source-graphql`,
    {
      resolve: "gatsby-source-graphql",
     options: {
      // This type will contain remote schema Query type
      typeName: "Query",
      // This is field under which it's accessible
      fieldName: "blah",
      // Url to query from
      url: "http://10.113.34.59:4000/graphql",
      // this is URL where served exposed its service in local
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

```
`gatsby-source-graphql`, <==== this caused the issue
{
  resolve: "gatsby-source-graphql",
 options: {
  // This type will contain remote schema Query type
  typeName: "Query",
  // This is field under which it's accessible
  fieldName: "blah",
  // Url to query from
  url: "http://10.113.34.59:4000/graphql",
  // this is URL where served exposed its service in local
},
```

Below worked fine

```
{
  resolve: "gatsby-source-graphql",
 options: {
  // This type will contain remote schema Query type
  typeName: "Query",
  // This is field under which it's accessible
  fieldName: "blah",
  // Url to query from
  url: "http://10.113.34.59:4000/graphql",
  // this is URL where served exposed its service in local
 },
```