# Gatsby-source-graphql requires option `fieldName` to be specified

Tags: graphql, gatsby, hasura

I am trying to get a demo app that uses Hasura and Gatsby started (https://github.com/praveenweb/dynamic-jamstack-gatsby-hasura/tree/master/dynamic-auth-client).

I edited the gatsby-config.js file with my Hasura endpoint URL, but I get the following error.

```
ERROR 

UNHANDLED REJECTION Type HASURA must define one or more fields.

  Error: Type HASURA must define one or more fields.
```

gatsby-config.js

```
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: "projectname",
    siteUrl: `https://www.myurlhere.com`,
  },
  plugins: [
    `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sitemap`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-nprogress`,
      options: {
        // Setting a color is optional.
        color: `tomato`,
        // Disable the loading spinner.
        showSpinner: false,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: "gatsby-source-graphql",
      options: {
        typeName: "HASURA",
        fieldName: "hasura",
        url: "https://myurlhere.com/v1/graphql",
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found I only need to make the typeName: "Query" and the fieldName: "blah".

[Error: Invariant Violation: gatsby-source-graphql requires option `typeName` to be specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55355700/error-invariant-violation-gatsby-source-graphql-requires-option-typename-to)

```
{
 resolve: "gatsby-source-graphql",
 options: {
  // This type will contain remote schema Query type
  typeName: "Query",
  // This is field under which it's accessible
  fieldName: "blah",
  // Url to query from
  url: "http://10.113.34.59:4000/graphql",
  // this is URL where served exposed its service in local
 },
```